# Iterate through Multidimensional array in plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, loops, multidimensional-array

I have the following Json file and I am trying to iterate through everything however only 1 item from the nested array is showing up. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

JSON:

```
{
   "items":[
      {
         "label":"red",
         "url":"red",
         "items":[

         ]
      },
      {
         "label":"blue",
         "url":"#/blue",
         "items":[
            {
               "label":"green",
               "url":"#/green"
            },
            {
               "label":"yellow",
               "url":"#/yellow"
            },
            {
               "label":"pink",
               "url":"#/pink"
            }
         ]
      },......
```

JS:

```
var d = document, 
        main = d.getElementsByTagName('nav')[ 0 ],
        ul = d.createElement( 'ul' ),
        i;

        main.appendChild( ul );

        axios.get('../data/colors.json')
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data.items);

            for( var i in response.data.items ){
                var li = d.createElement( 'li' ); 
                if(response.data.items[i].items.length){
                    li.innerHTML = "<a class='meta'>" + response.data.items[i].label + "<div>" + response.data.items[i].items[i].label + "</div>" + "</a>"; // create a new li element
                }
                else {
                    li.innerHTML = "<a class='meta'>" + response.data.items[i].label + "</a>"; // create a new li element
                }
                ul.appendChild( li );// every time append a new item

            }

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Desired output:

```
<ul>
<li>red<li>
<li>blue
  <div>green </div>
  <div>yellow </div>
  <div>pink</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `for( var i in response.data.items ){` - don't use `for..in` on an array, use a regular `for` loop - `for..in` is for iterating the properties of an object.

Comment: Or use the new [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

Comment: What is the result you're looking for?

Comment: Just updated with desired result

Comment: @user992731 - Please try my suggestion - a regular `for` loop will solve your problems

Comment: I don't have time to write it out for you. But this would be a great case for a recursive `Array.map()`. Define a mapping function that calls itself if there are items on an item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to iterate/loop over the nested items, which you aren't doing. Basically add another loop for the 2nd level of items.

Here's a cleaned up version: http://jsfiddle.net/DennisRas/zyn52p8v/
Note: I've removed the .axios module to show what's important.

```
const data = {
   "items":[
      {
         "label":"red",
         "url":"red",
         "items":[

         ]
      },
      {
         "label":"blue",
         "url":"#/blue",
         "items":[
            {
               "label":"green",
               "url":"#/green"
            },
            {
               "label":"yellow",
               "url":"#/yellow"
            },
            {
               "label":"pink",
               "url":"#/pink"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "label":"blue",
         "url":"#/blue",
         "items":[
            {
               "label":"green",
               "url":"#/green"
            },
            {
               "label":"yellow",
               "url":"#/yellow"
            },
            {
               "label":"pink",
               "url":"#/pink"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "label":"blue",
         "url":"#/blue",
         "items":[
            {
               "label":"green",
               "url":"#/green"
            },
            {
               "label":"yellow",
               "url":"#/yellow"
            },
            {
               "label":"pink",
               "url":"#/pink"
            }
         ]
      }
    ]
};

const nav = document.querySelector('nav');
const ul = document.createElement( 'ul' );

nav.appendChild(ul);

data.items.forEach(function(item) {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  let html = "<a class='meta'>" + item.label;

  if (item.items && item.items.length) {
    item.items.forEach(function(subitem) {
        html += "<div>" + subitem.label + "</div>";
    });
  }

  html += "</a>";

  li.innerHTML = html;
  ul.appendChild(li);// every time append a new item
});

console.log(data.items);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it -

```js
var data = {
  "items": [{
      "label": "red",
      "url": "red",
      "items": [

      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "blue",
      "url": "#/blue",
      "items": [{
          "label": "green",
          "url": "#/green"
        },
        {
          "label": "yellow",
          "url": "#/yellow"
        },
        {
          "label": "pink",
          "url": "#/pink"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

var createList = function(response) {
  var d = document,
    main = d.getElementById('list'),
    ul = d.createElement('ul'),
    i;

  main.appendChild(ul);

  //console.log(response.data.items);

  for (var i in response.data.items) {
    var li = d.createElement('li');
    if (response.data.items[i].items.length) {
      li.innerHTML = "<a class='meta'>" + response.data.items[i].label + "</a>"; // create a new li element
      ul.appendChild(li); // every time append a new item
      var innerul = d.createElement('ul');
      for (var j in response.data.items[i].items) {
        var innerli = d.createElement('li');
        innerli.innerHTML = "<div>" + response.data.items[i].items[j].label + "</div>"; // create a new li element
        innerul.appendChild(innerli);

      }
      li = innerul;
    } else {

      li.innerHTML = "<a class='meta'>" + response.data.items[i].label + "</a>"; // create a new li element
      ul.appendChild(li); // every time append a new item
    }
    ul.appendChild(li); // every time append a new item
  }

}

createList({
  data: data
});
```

```html
<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: I am getting duplication issues

Comment: @user992731 I've updated answer to create sublist in case when there are items available

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take. You'll want to use recursion to print out the list.

```
function printList(list,container){
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    list.forEach(function(item){
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = '<div class="meta">' + item.label + '</div>';
        if(item.hasOwnProperty('items')){
            printList(item.items,li);
        }
        ul.appendChild(li);
    });
    container.appendChild(ul);
}
```

To use it:

```
axios.get('../data/colors.json').then(function (response) {
    printList(response.data.items,document.body);
})
```

```js
function printList(list,container){
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    list.forEach(function(item){
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = '<div class="meta">' + item.label + '</div>';
        if(item.hasOwnProperty('items')){
            printList(item.items,li);
        }
        ul.appendChild(li);
    });
  container.appendChild(ul);
}

var items = {
   "items":[
      {
         "label":"red",
         "url":"red",
         "items":[

         ]
      },
      {
         "label":"blue",
         "url":"#/blue",
         "items":[
            {
               "label":"green",
               "url":"#/green"
            },
            {
               "label":"yellow",
               "url":"#/yellow"
            },
            {
               "label":"pink",
               "url":"#/pink"
            }
         ]
      }
     ]
}

printList(items.items,document.body);

console.log();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple recursive function that accepts the html element you want to append to and an object. An advantage of this approach is that will work to arbitrary depths and it maintains the nesting rather than flattening everything out. Most of the work is manipulating the HTML — other than that it's a very simple idea:

```js
let obj = {"items":[{"label":"red","url":"red","items":[]},{"label":"blue","url":"#/blue","items":[{"label":"green","url":"#/green"},{"label":"yellow","url":"#/yellow"},{"label":"pink","url":"#/pink"}]}]}

function addItems(parent, obj) {
    let keys = Object.keys(obj)
    for (key of keys) {
      let o = obj[key]      
      let li = document.createElement('li')
      if (Array.isArray(o)) {
        let text = document.createTextNode(key);
        li.appendChild(text)
        let ul = document.createElement('ul')
        o.forEach(item => addItems(ul, item))
        li.appendChild(ul)
      } else {
        li.innerText = key + ': ' + o
      }
      parent.appendChild(li)
    }
}

let list = document.getElementById('1')
addItems(list, obj)
```

```html
<ul id="1">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you are looping over the nested items array. You are only looping over the parent array.

If there are items in the nested array, add another loop for it. For example

```
for (var j in response.data.items[i].items) {
  li.innerHTML = "<a class='meta'>" + response.data.items[i].label + "<div>" + response.data.items[i].items[j].label + "</div>" + "</a>"; // create a new li element
}
```

I think there are better patterns to do a for loop, but I am just keeping your pattern here. Basically root cause, you aren't looping over the nested items.